# Parse Cloud Code function Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having some trouble in executing a function because I keep getting the same error concerning my masterKey not being provided:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"changeUserModeratorStatus" withParameters:@{@"objectId": self.objId}];
```

The function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("changeUserModeratorStatus", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);
  query.first({
    success: function(anotherUser) {
      anotherUser.set("ModeratorStatus", "Approved");
      anotherUser.save(null, {
      success: function(anotherUser) {
        response.success("Successfully updated user.");
      },
    error: function(failedRetrieve, error) {
     response.error("Could not save changes to user.");
    }
   });
   },
   error: function(error) {
    response.error("Could not find user."); 
   }
  });
});
```

Edit, i've literally copy/pasted Hectors example on the forums, checked the documents and haven't found a solution. No matter what I do, I get an error : Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing the master key in the initialization of your cloud code -

```
 Parse.initialize(applicationId, javaScriptKey, masterKey).
```

Taking out the whole initialization fixed the problem for me since `Parse` actually initializes your cloud code with your `application id`, `JavaScript key` and `master key` so you don't have to do it.

Comment: It won't let me do it this way since I'm not using node.js

Comment: I had the same problem. Just take out the initialization and that will fix the problem

Comment: It wouldn't let me deploy last time trying that but I'll give it a go tonight and let you know.

Comment: yeah, I previously included the initialization because I couldn't deploy without it but it now works without the initialization

Comment: This worked thank you. However, it's not `Parse.initialize(#,#,masterKey)` because that's just for node.js, what worked for me was deleting the line entirely

Comment: While it's true that Parse does this automatically for you in cloud code, if you deploy your cloud code to heroku instead, you must still call `Parse.initialize()` manually with these keys or you'll get the error about the master key missing. Note that Parse automatically passes in the app ID and master key as heroku config env vars; you'll need to add the javascript key too.